# Run msbuild task with an external condition

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, msbuild-target

Is it possible to ignore a target in a proj file? Anything of the sort of

```
msbuild amazingproject.proj /IgnoreTarget:TimeConsumingTarget
```

or can we set a condition value for the target while calling msbuild?

```
msbuild amazingproject.proj /Variable:TimeConsumingCondition=False
```

& in the proj file we can have

```
<targed name="TimeConsumingTarget" Condition="$(Variable:TimeConsumingCondition)"=="True">
```

Any other suggestion that works?

The whole story:
We have many developers, some of whom need this target to run and some don't. So we need a conditional call for the target.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just look at the documentation of [Target](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t50z2hka.aspx).

Project:

```
<Target Name="TimeConsumingTarget"
        Condition="'$(BuildTimeConsumingTarget)'=='True'">
```

Invoked like:

```
msbuild amazingproject.proj /p:BuildTimeConsumingTarget=false
```